# How to render multiple plots and tables in Rmarkdown using a loop

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am working on a `Rmarkdown` document to show some plots and tables. The code works fine but I got the issue that there are many plots and tables so the process of adding them is really large. My code is next (I need to render to word document):

````
---
title: "My document"
output: word_document
date: '2022-06-28'
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Analysis

```{r t1}
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
#Data
data("iris")
iris
#Create list for plots and tables
List <- split(iris,iris$Species)
#Create plots
plotfun <- function(x)
{
  y <- ggplot(x,aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width))+
    geom_point()
  return(y)
}
#Create tables
tablefun <- function(x)
{
  y <- x %>% group_by(Species) %>%
    summarise_all(sum)
  return(y)
}
#Create list of plots and tables
Lplots <- lapply(List, plotfun)
Ltables <- lapply(List, tablefun)
```
````

Until that is fine. The trouble appears when I need to print the plots and tables. I use this code:

````
```{r,echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,fig.cap=paste0("Figure 1","My plot"),fig.pos='H',fig.align='center',out.width='100%',fig.height=5,fig.width=9}
Lplots[[1]]
```

```{r,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
kable(Ltables[[1]],caption = paste("Table 1: Summary"),align = c('l',rep('c',4)))
```
````

But if I have 100 plots and tables, it would be very extensive.

Can somebody help me how I can do something like this:

````
for(i in 1:length(Lplots))
{

```{r,echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,fig.cap=paste0("Figure ",i,"My plot"),fig.pos='H',fig.align='center',out.width='100%',fig.height=5,fig.width=9}
Lplots[[i]]
```

```{r,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
kable(Ltables[[i]],caption = paste("Table",i," : Summary"),align = c('l',rep('c',4)))
```
}
````

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to print the plots and tables in your rmarkdown and not save them, you can 1. change code chunk option to `results = 'asis'` 2. wrap each function call in `print()` and 3. assign results to some dummy object ("suppress"). If you don't do this it will print ugly output, like NULL or the group title as if it were console output. You'll want to assign to dummy object within each print call and assign the whole function call. I'd guess you'd want your tables and plots together by group, so you can put them in one loop.

```
{r,echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,fig.pos='H',fig.align='center',out.width='100%',fig.height=5,fig.width=9, results='asis'}

lapply(1:length(List), function(i) {
  print(plotfun(List[[i]]) +
    ggtitle(paste("My Plot", i)) -> suppress)
  print(kable(tablefun(List[[i]]),caption = sprintf("Table %s: Summary", i),align = c('l',rep('c',4)))) -> suppress
  }) -> suppress
```

I removed your fig.caption option in code chunk and printed plot and table number dynamically. This should knit into whatever desired output.

Comment: just wanted to emphasize that there are two assignments to the `suppress` dummy variable - one for each print of kable table within the loop, and one for the loop itself. i missed this before but then saw it on second glance

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to save the plots by putting the loop within the code chunk.

```
for(i in length(lPlots)){
    ggsave(fname,lPlots[[i])
}
```

Another useful option for at least for plots is to use pwalk() as shown here https://cmdlinetips.com/2022/06/create-a-list-of-ggplot-objects-and-save-them-as-files/